# Fiddler Core not capturing anything

Tags: c#, fiddlercore

I wanted to test FiddlerCore.

Found this -> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d9e6f2/capturing-http-traffic-in-C-Sharp/

I wrote it but for me it not capturing.

My code:

```
delegate void UpdateUI();
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete;
   Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(0, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);
}
void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Fiddler.Session oSession)
{
   listBox1.Invoke(new UpdateUI(() =>
   {
      listBox1.Items.Add(oSession.url);
   }));
}
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Rather than starting with their example, try starting with the Demo project that ships with FiddlerCore itself. You should also update your question to mention what client application you're using, and what URLs you're trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Have you wired Form Load and Form Closing events to the form? Can you please provide source of InitializeComponent() method. 
I suspect that you are missing this:

```
this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

Btw, what OS are you using?

Comment: I solved it by chaning Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(0, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default); to Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(0,true,true);